# does Voice of the Chain Master effectively replace Devil's Sight If the warlock's familiar is an imp?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars

to me, the Voice of the Chain Master invocation reads that it completely upgrades the basic Find Familiar spell, increasing the range of the telepathic communication to 100 feet and no longer requiring an action to perceive through its senses.

I have read Crawford's Sage Advice saying you still require an action, but that was 4 years ago and he is known to change his rulings (though it might not have changed, just that people have not asked in a while)